# Gedolim on Spanish Flu

Tags: choleh-sick, history

Did the Gedolim of the time during whcih the Spanish Flu was spreading (and killed anywhere from 17 million to 50 million people) comment on it and provide any halachic guidance on whether to permit minyan and what to do regarding seder?  Anything relevant to what is happening now with covid-19 and how the Gedolim of that era responded would be of interest to me.  Especially the Chofetz Chaim.

Comment: https://jewishcurrents.org/the-1918-flu-epidemic/